# How to cleanup themes/icons that I messed up

Tags: unity, apt, themes, icons

I've been playing a bit too much with my custom themes/icons.
I started by copying them from /usr/share/themes (/icons) to ~/.themes (.icons).  Then afterwards decided to delete the original files to clean up my list in the unity tweak tool (2 entries).  And now in all my wisdom I accidentely deleted them from my home folder.

Nothing too serious so far.  Problem is that I can no longer install them again via apt-get ...  Get a warning about 'package is already at latest version'.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: When I copy theme or icon folders over from /usr/share, I rename them so that I know which is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reinstall a package by opening a terminal (Alt+Control+T) and using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nameofpackage
```

(replacing `nameofpackage` with your package's name).

If you prefer a GUI for advanced package management, do yourself a favor and ditch the Software Center -- use a proper package manager such as Synaptic or Muon that allows you to reinstall packages, or you can use the ncurses-based Aptitude on the command line.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.